# jQuery $.ajaxError() runs on 200 - OK

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a global ajax error handler that runs even though the xhr.status is 200, xhr.statusText is "OK" and xhr.responseText is my JSON string. This happens in firefox and IE.

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        method: "getRequestDetails",
        loggedInUsername: loggedInUsername,
        search: search
    },
    success: function(data){
        var arrayObject = eval("(" + data + ")")['DATA'];
        if (arrayObject.length == 0){
            alert("That search term returned no results");
        } else {
            callBeforeShow("Results");
            $.each(arrayObject, function(index, value){
                showJSON(value, "Results");
            });
            callAfterShow("Results");
        }
    }
});

$(document).ajaxError(function(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    var errorMessage = "Ajax Error\n";
    errorMessage += "Type: " + ajaxOptions.type + "\n";
    errorMessage += "Requesting Page: " + ajaxOptions.url + "\n";
    errorMessage += "Status: " + XMLHttpRequest.status + " - " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText + "\n";
    errorMessage += "Error Thrown: " + thrownError
    alert(errorMessage);
});
```

In IE this says that the XMLHttpRequest is not ready and in Firefox this returns

"AJAX Error"
"Type: POST"
"Requesting Page: something.CFC"
"Status: 200 - OK"
"Error Thrown: undefined"

So my work around is to use

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, errorThrown){
    if (XMLHttpRequest.status != 200){
        var errorMessage = "Ajax Error\n";
        errorMessage += "Type: " + ajaxOptions.type + "\n";
        errorMessage += "Requesting Page: " + ajaxOptions.url + "\n";
        errorMessage += "Status: " + XMLHttpRequest.status + " - " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText;
        alert(errorMessage);
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
**This only happens on some occassions. Most of the time it works but sometimes it runs $.ajaxError()**
**EIDT**

```
{"COLUMNS":["ID","SUMMARY_SPEC","TOTAL_EFFORT","EFFORT_HISTORY","LOG_HISTORY"],"DATA":[[816,"test only","2 Minutes - Last Updated: 09\/12\/2010",{"COLUMNS":["CC_ID","RECORD_ID","USER_ID","USER_NAME","EFFORT_DATE","EFFORT_DAYS","EFFORT_HRS","EFFORT_MINS","EFFORT_TOT_HRS"],"DATA":[[816,496,"ruhlet","Tim Ruhle","December, 09 2010 00:00:00",0,0,1,0.0167],[816,497,"ruhlet","Tim Ruhle","December, 08 2010 00:00:00",0,0,1,0.0167]]},{"COLUMNS":["CC_ID","RECORD_ID","USER_ID","USER_NAME","LOG_DT","LOG_ENTRY"],"DATA":[]}]]}{"COLUMNS":["ID","SUMMARY_SPEC","TOTAL_EFFORT","EFFORT_HISTORY","LOG_HISTORY"],"DATA":[[816,"test only","2 Minutes - Last Updated: 09\/12\/2010",{"COLUMNS":["CC_ID","RECORD_ID","USER_ID","USER_NAME","EFFORT_DATE","EFFORT_DAYS","EFFORT_HRS","EFFORT_MINS","EFFORT_TOT_HRS"],"DATA":[[816,496,"ruhlet","Tim Ruhle","December, 09 2010 00:00:00",0,0,1,0.0167],[816,497,"ruhlet","Tim Ruhle","December, 08 2010 00:00:00",0,0,1,0.0167]]},{"COLUMNS":["CC_ID","RECORD_ID","USER_ID","USER_NAME","LOG_DT","LOG_ENTRY"],"DATA":[]}]]}{"COLUMNS":["ID","SUMMARY_SPEC","TOTAL_EFFORT","EFFORT_HISTORY","LOG_HISTORY"],"DATA":[[816,"test only","2 Minutes - Last Updated: 09\/12\/2010",{"COLUMNS":["CC_ID","RECORD_ID","USER_ID","USER_NAME","EFFORT_DATE","EFFORT_DAYS","EFFORT_HRS","EFFORT_MINS","EFFORT_TOT_HRS"],"DATA":[[816,496,"ruhlet","Tim Ruhle","December, 09 2010 00:00:00",0,0,1,0.0167],[816,497,"ruhlet","Tim Ruhle","December, 08 2010 00:00:00",0,0,1,0.0167]]},{"COLUMNS":["CC_ID","RECORD_ID","USER_ID","USER_NAME","LOG_DT","LOG_ENTRY"],"DATA":[]}]]}
```

The latest version of firebug recognises it as json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah, well after days of searching i commented out different settings in $.ajaxSetup(). It ended up being that i had set a timeout. If only there was a better error message given. Thanks for all the help guys, would not have gotten here if not for you. You all get up votes!!!

Comment: Did you figure out why a timeout caused this? Did you stick with your original ajaxComplete handler or find a more graceful method? I'm getting this problem as well, and I don't understand it.

Comment: No i didn't find out. I was already behind schedule trying to fix it, so i just accepted that it worked and i probably would never know why. Sorry

Answer (score 5):

First off, I'd highly recommend ditching the `eval` part in favor of using $.parseJson or the `dataType:'json'` ajax option that automatically handles the parsing (for reasons of performance and security among other things).  If you do continue to use `eval`, at the very least wrap it it a try catch.

I'm not entirely sure of every case where ajaxError gets called but I suspect (based of the the "randomness" of the error) that it has to do with an error inside the success function (like `eval` being called on invalid javascript that you're getting in your response).  This would explain why it is getting called even when there is a 200 response.

tldr: Get `eval` out of that `success` callback and assert that your responses are in fact valid json when this error occurs.

Comment: This is on a work intranet. We are using jQuery 1.3.2 and it could be a major hassle to try and get the latest version (which is needed for $.parseJson(). And i couldn't use the javascript JSON.parse() or whatever it is becuase we are using IE7 which doesn't support the JSON object. The error is run before the eval anyway.

Comment: When you get the error, can you include the json response you are getting?  Due to the random nature and errors you describe I suspect it has something to do with the actual response being sent back.  Also the dataType:'json' option is available in jQuery 1.3.2.  I would highly encourage using it.

Comment: Nothing works at all when i specify dataType. Edited to include returned json string.

Comment: @jthompson how am i meant to use that?

Comment: Did you wrap your eval statement in a try catch? You have a parse error in the JSON provided.  Try it on http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 3):

Could it be because you are not telling `$.ajax` that you are expecting JSON back from the server? Try setting the `dataType` option to 'json':

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { ...
```

Comment: i have like 10 other ajax calls on the page, some using plain and others using json and they work fine without that declaration. But i will give it a go any way.

Comment: Now firebug is doing this. uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.status]" nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location: "JS frame :: myUrl.js :: anonymous :: line 146" data: no]. Line 146 is line 4 in $.ajaxError()

Answer (score 1):

I get two errors when I copy&paste that json to this formatter/validator http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

2 x comma missing between }{.